# default compilation sdk eroor

Tags: react-native, sdk

I'm having some errors while building an android react-native project regarding SDK compilation.

I've tried environment variable change, node.js change, and gradle wrapper change already.

```
Could not get unknown property 'DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.
```

Comment: Have you installed android studio? Do you have the mininum required version of the SDK?

Comment: yes,i have downloded the latest version of android studio and sdk ,